# Cannot register for Windows Azure

Tags: azure, registration, bizspark

I am a bizspark client and want to register to windows azure.
However, as soon as it comes to the account verification via mobile, I get the following error message:
[image: entering mobile number]

[image: getting the error]
My mobile number is absolutely correct. And getting verified by a phone call did not work either. (same error message)

The most frustrating thing however is, that I cannot find any support form of microsoft. They only relay to stackoverflow or the msdn forums. That's kind of a bad joke, right?
Could you please tell me where I can send my complaints to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several calls to the windows live team, the result was, that they somehow screwed up my live id. They fixed it internally and now it works.
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

FYI, for anyone still running into this - you can work around the issue by first adding a credit card at https://commerce.microsoft.com/PaymentHub/PaymentInstrument (accessed via account.live.com -> Billing -> Payment Information)

Adding a credit card there will not error like the Azure portal does. Return to Azure afterward and it will pull the credit in automatically, bypassing whatever broken check has been there for two years..